# Array to string conversion laravel

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

In my blade view I have inputs like this:

```
<input type="time" class="" name="shipping_hours[saturday][from]" value="" />
<input type="time" class="" name="shipping_hours[saturday][to]" value="" />
<input type="checkbox" name="shipping_hours[saturday][all_day]" /> <label class="">24h</label>
```

And I have a table, `shipping_hours` in a mysql database. I want save data in this JSON format:

```
{"monday":{"from":"13:00","to":"22:00"},"tuesday":{"from":"13:00","to":"22:00"},"wednesday":{"from":"13:00","to":"22:00"},"thursday":{"from":"13:00","to":"22:00"},"friday":{"from":"13:00","to":"01:00"},"saturday":{"from":"13:00","to":"01:00"},"sunday":{"from":"12:00","to":"22:00"}}
```

How I can do this in laravel?

**Controller** (store funtion)

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $this->validator($request->all())->validate();
    settings_hours::create($data);
    session()->flash('message_success', "Object added");
    return redirect(route('hours'));        
}
```

**Controller** (validator function)

```
protected function validator($data) {
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'place_id' => 'required',
        'opening_hours.*' => 'nullable',
        'kitchen_hours.*' => 'nullable',
        'shipping_hours.*' => 'nullable',
        'breakfast_hours.*' => 'nullable',
        'launch_hours.*' => 'nullable',
        'reservation_hours.*' => 'nullable'
    ]);
}
```

**Model**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class settings_hours extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'place_id',
        'opening_hours',
        'kitchen_hours',
        'shipping_hours',
        'breakfast_hours',
        'launch_hours',
        'reservation_hours'
    ];
}
```

Comment: Welcome. SO question need to a certain format to be appropriate for our platform. What did you try? And what was the result of you attempt? How did it differ from what you expected? We're any error messages generated? Please review [how to ask](https://StackOverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then `edit` accordingly. Without this info, the Question reads like a "give me the code," free coding service question, or a request for a tutorial, which disllowed. SO is designed to handle *specific* coding issues, bugs, etc. Add additional info allows our volunteer community can help you resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string='hello,min,max';    
implode(',',$array);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Most answers will benefit from an explanation to help visitors hone in on the important elements of your solution. Explanations increase long term value allowing uture visitors to learn from & apply your knowledge to their own code, keeps quality of SO high, & encourages the use of SO platform as a knowledge base, rather than a "give me the code" or, free coding service. Eplanations are usually quicker to digest/understand than strictly interpreting code, & helps distinguish your solution with other solutions. Well crafted answers are more often upvoted

Answer (score 0):

In model im added this code and is worked, i think is be helpful

```
    protected $casts = [
    'place_id' => 'integer',
    'opening_hours' => 'array',
    'kitchen_hours' => 'array',
    'shipping_hours' => 'array',
    'breakfast_hours' => 'array',
    'launch_hours' => 'array',
    'reservation_hours' => 'array'
];
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on SO. Most answers will benefit from an explanation to help visitors hone in on the important elements of your solution. Explanations increase long term value allowing uture visitors to learn from & apply your knowledge to their own code, keeps quality of SO high, & encourages the use of SO platform as a knowledge base, rather than a "give me the code" or, free coding service. Eplanations are usually quicker to digest/understand than strictly interpreting code, & helps distinguish your solution with other solutions. Well crafted answers are more often upvoted